# Debug symbol bug with MacPorts installed GCC 4.9?

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, gdb, macports

I have recently installed GCC 4.9.2 (port name gcc49) through MacPorts. I am quite happy with its new features such as colorized diagnostics and C++1y/C++14 support improvements, etc.

However, since I started to compile code using GCC 4.9.2, I realized that it is not generating debug symbol directory `*.dSYM` and gdb says "no debugging symbols found" when I try to debug a program I compiled with `-g` flag.

Is this a MacPorts specific bug or is there a problem with GCC 4.9?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a MacPorts specific issue.  MacPorts doesn't really do much to customize the gcc ports.

If you want to create a dSYM bundle and strip your executable, you should just do something like:

```
gcc-mp-4.9 -g3 -c example.c 
gcc-mp-4.9 example.o -o example
dsymutil --out example.dSYM example
strip -S -x example
```

As a side note, if you want C++11/C++14 support, I suggest you use the clang-3.5 port as that will allow you to use libc++ from the system instead of libstdc++ from MacPorts (and allow you to use system and MacPorts C++ libraries rather than just the STL).  Also, lldb is really the preferred debugger for OS X these days.

Comment: Thanks, it worked but I liked using just `-g` with `gcc-mp-4.8` to get the debug symbol directory. And I should start using lldb indeed...